# trouble with parse error

Tags: php

thanks in advance, 
I'v added `mobile detect` library to my wordpress site (its a pre made theme with a child theme ).

I'v tried to run these code, but i'm keep on getting this error, I'v searched this group there are lots of answers none worked for me

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'`

what am I doing wrong ? thanks to all 
[library site](http://mobiledetect.net/)

```
<?php if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
    <div>
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'checkout/layouts/test.php' ) ?> ;
    </div>
} ?>
```

Comment: That's because your PHP syntax is wrong. You have to close PHP before HTML's `<div>` using `?>` like you do in the line #3. Also, you don't need semicolon there. See _[Basic syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php) -> [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)_.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply appreciate, iv changed my code to this [link](https://pastebin.com/8ekPCG9T), and now I'm getting this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file `

Comment: never mind bro you helped a lot Iv changed it again all that was missing is `<?php } ?>` got it. just for knowledge is this true in all php files ?

Comment: Yes. But you should omit the closing `?>` at the very end of the PHP file because it can cause "_Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (...)_" error in some cases.

Comment: I understand, but this the theme file I'm just adding stuff to it if its not there  I guess there is a reason, but Il try these anyway. thanks for help appreciate a lot all works great :) keep it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the logic is correct, the fault lies in your PHP syntax. This would be correct:

```
<?php if ( $detect->isMobile() ) { ?>
<div>
    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'checkout/layouts/test.php' ); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, in first line `?>` was still missing

Comment: thanks @Robin k I'v got it in the end, thank you that's what Max Yudin mentioned as well (noby erros) , but I never say no for more knowledge thanks guys learnt a lot :)

Comment: @Osh you are very welcome :)